# Read data from tables returned from inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, subquery

So, I am working on a project where I need to find all tables that have the column `xyz`, and then remove all rows from such tables if the updated_at date for that row from that table is older than some duration.

I got the list of all tables from SQL Server like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN
    sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    c.name = 'xyz';
```

Now I want to use each of the tables returned from this query to DELETE all rows from these tables which satisfy some criteria. Can someone help me with the 'Nested query' please?

Answer (score 3):

What you're contemplating isn't going to work; you need to explicitly specify which table you are deleting from in a `delete` statement.

My approach would be to use your query to dynamically generate the `delete` statements, then save the output of your query in a file, and run the file.  This also gives you a chance to review and double-check the deletes before you run them, which is a good idea when you're making large-scale data changes like these.

```
select
  'delete from ' + t.name + ' where updated_at <= ''2013-01-01'';'
from
  sys.tables t
where 
  exists (select null from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.name = 'xyz')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/475c0/2

Comment: I try to avoid exists wherever possible because of the multiple executions required to execute it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/475c0/4

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible to categorically determine that one approach (exists vs. join) is better than another in all possible circumstances.  I went with my approach to make it explicit that you're only getting one row per table.  The `distinct` in your query does that too, but `distinct` has its costs as well.  In any case, I don't think performance of this query is going to be a significant issue in a production environment (compared to the performance of mass deletion when the OP executes the script that is produced by the query).

Comment: Not meant as a criticism by any means, just food for thought. I have a particular database with 100,000+ tables on it (not my design) so I have a slightly different perspective on this particular query.

Comment: No worries, @David.  And 100K tables, ouch!

Comment: Taking on from what jokeeffe suggested, instead of writing queries to a file, I would much rather prefer running them directly by storing them in an 'list of strings' (each string being the query to be run). From what I understand about SQL Server (I just started learning SQL Server), one variable can only have 1 value - it cannot take a list of values. Does SQL Server not support storing list of values in a variable (an array, may be?)